# How can I remove vanishing derivatives of hypergeometric functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have a lot of expressions containing derivatives of hypergeometric functions of the sort:

$$_2F_1^{(0,0,1,0)} \left(\frac{1}{2} , 1 ; \frac{3}{2} ; 0 \right). \tag{1}$$

The last argument is always $0$. This is not evaluated, but if I used `N` then it evaluates to $0$. How can such expressions consistently be removed from my expressions?

Consider the following example (sorry I do not know how to properly format the hypergeometric function in the code environment, it's just copy-paste):

```
15 g^2 f[1] \[CapitalDelta]c[1] - 30 g^2 f[1] \[CapitalDelta]c[1] \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Hypergeometric2F1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], ")"}], Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[1/2, 2, 5/2, 0]
```

The second term evaluates to $0$ with `N`. I can use `/.{... -> N[...]}` but since I have a lot of functions it would be better to use something else.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, but what if I have other hypergeometric functions which vanish, for example `Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0]Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 5/2, 0]`?

Comment: @BobHanlon Your answer works great. What about turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace expressions that numerically evaluate to zero with zero.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 3/2, 0] + 
  Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 3/2, 0] + 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 3/2, 0] +
  Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1/2, 1, 5/2, 0]  /. 
 _?(N[#] == 0 &) :> 0 

(* 0 *)
```